# What is the distribution of $e^{i\Theta}$ when $\Theta \sim \text{Unif}[-\pi, \pi]$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, random-functions

I am stuck in a derivation where, in one of the steps, I have to find the distribution of the following function:
$$h = z_1e^{i\theta_1} + z_2e^{i\theta_2} + \cdots + z_ne^{i\theta_n},$$
where $\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_n$ are all i.i.d distributed $\text{Unif}[-\pi, \pi]$ and $z_1, \cdots,z_n$ are complex constants.

I tried writing $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$ and then find the distributions of $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ seperately. If
$X=\cos\theta$, I got the pdf of $X$ to be $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Q1) I have difficulty deriving the distribution of $\sin\theta$. I don't know how to go on.

Q2) Let us say, I get some expression for the pdf of $\sin \theta$, how do I go on further?

Q3) Can someone suggest some other method to directly get the distribution of $e^{i\theta}$, without getting into $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ business?

Comment: Note that $\{ e^{i \theta} | \theta \in [-\pi, \pi] \}$ is the unit circle in the complex plane, and note that the length of an arc on this circle is simply equal to the angle $\Delta \theta$ subtended.

Comment: Could you please tell us the context? what are you trying to do with this distribution?

Comment: Try to visualize the range of the random variable in the complex plane, starting from $n=1$ and increasing its value. You should see that equiprobable zones are concentric circular crowns. You *only* have to find the radii of the circles, and the probability in each such crown.